# Should we use @Scheduled together with controller method (like @PostMaping) in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, spring-batch

I'm using `SpringBatch` but I cant find any document or tutorial about Spring's `@Scheduled` , showing it being used along side with some controller method (annotated with `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`).

For example, I have this controller method

```java
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * ? * *")
    @PostMapping("/create-progress-data")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createSomething(@Request Something request) { }
```

I can easily create another method that do the same thing as in the body of `createSomething` then put it in a `@Component` or a `Service`, but between doing that and just applying `@Scheduled` on top of the controller method, I don't know which one is better.

I can see that:

- Using `@Scheduled` : code is minimal, works just find. But we're kind of using the controller method in the wrong way. However I don't see it violates Single responsibility point in design pattern.
- Create another method and put it in other `@Component` or `@Service`: separate the duty of the controller method and the cron job but duplicate the code.

Ps: I need to implement it like this because we need to support two ways to trigger the job. Either via api call (controller method), or periodically (with `@Scheduled`).

Please notice in this case the code of controller method and the expected cron job is the same.

Comment: You could but you shouldn't as that is mixing concepts, next it wouldn't work  in this case as `@Scheduled` works only on no-arg methods.

Comment: Ah, I've tried it with no arguments `@GetMapping`, I thought it would also work with `@PostMapping`, thanks

Comment: Well as stated you really shouldn't mix those things. Also if you feel the urge or need to place that `@Scheduled` on a controller method imho your controller is doing too much and part of that should be moved to a service. You can than make a simple component using `@Scheduled` invoking the same service method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is better to separate the two ways of launching your jobs. You can use the controller for API-based on-demand job launches, and use the `@Scheduled` way for a background process that launches jobs on the defined schedule.

That said, you should take into consideration the concurrency policy for your job definitions. For example, what should your system do if a job launch request comes through the API and tries to launch the same job that has been launched by a schedule (which could be running at that time)?. There are other use cases, but those depend on your requirement.

Comment: But what if we have a different controller and scheduler in the same project? Will the controller and scheduler be running on individual seperate threads so that both functionalities will be up?

Comment: Web requests and scheduling requests can be served using the same thread pool or different thread pools, so it depends on your configuration.